# How to add (not set) value to include filter in google analytics

Tags: filter, google-analytics

I want to add location filters to the view for only if city is "Mumbai". However, in the data, city shows as "(not set)" sometimes. I don't want to exclude this data.

I tried creating a custom include filter with filter pattern as "Mumbai|(not set)". It doesn't work. It filters for Mumbai but not for the unknown locations.

How can I have a geographical view and not ignore the hits from unknown locations?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the filter pattern `ga:city!=(not set)`.

Test your filter with the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) and check out the [filter reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters).

Good luck!